# "anchor" text showing on hover content

Tags: css

I have two horizontal dropdown menu. when i hover first "li" is show upper in the second dorpdown menu but problem is second dropdown anchor text is not go down. kindly help me what is the actual reason to showing anchor text in the upper of hover content. for your information i already try "Z-index" and position Properties.

Note: This two are separate file i will include in this two page in one php file.

[image]

```css
#primary_nav_wrap
{
 
 height:40px;
 margin-top:11px;
 background:#fff;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:14px;
 line-height:40px;
 padding:0 70px 0 20px;
 letter-spacing:.2em;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 position:relative;
 z-index:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap .arrow:after
{
 content:'\203A';
 font-size:24px;
 color:#000;
 float:right;
 margin-right:5px;
 margin-top:-32px;
 transform:rotate(90deg);
 -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
 -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover .arrow:after
 {
  content:'\2039';
 }

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item img
{
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 padding:5px 5px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a:before
{
 content:'\203A';
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-right:10px;
 color:black;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:250px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">

 <div class="mainbody">
  
  <ul>
        <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="index.php"><img src="./icon/home.png"/></a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Men's</a><span class="arrow"></span>
           <ul>
          <li><a href="">Traditional Wear</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Top Wear</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bottom Wear</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bags</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Accessories</a></li>
        </ul>
          <li>
     <li><a href="#">Women's</a><span class="arrow"></span>
           <ul>
          <li><a href="">Traditional Wear</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Westen Wear</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lingerie</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bages</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Jewellery</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Accessories</a></li>
           </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Kids</a><span class="arrow"></span>
           <ul>
          <li class="dir"><a href="#">Boy's</a>
     <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
          <li class="dir"><a href="#">Girl's</a>
     <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dir"><a href="#">Baby</a>
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
           </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Home & Living</a><span class="arrow"></span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Kitchen Decor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Bathroom Decor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Bedroom Decor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Dining Decor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Drawing Decor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Furniture</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Lighting</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Textile and Rugs</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Office Stationery</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
     <li><a href="#">Garden</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Offer Zone</a></li>
     </ul> 
 </div>
</nav>
```

```css
#part2
 {
  width:400px;
  height:60px;
  float:right;
 }
 
#part2 ul
  { 
   text-decoration:none;
   list-style:none;
   text-align:center;
  }
#part2 ul li
  {
   float: left;
   padding:15px 25px 15px 25px;
   height:30px;
   cursor:pointer;
  }
  
.num
 {
  font-size:18px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#FF0000;
  font-style:normal;
  font-size-adjust:none;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height:30px;
  top:-15px;
  right:-5px;
  position:relative;
 }
   
#part2 ul li:hover
   {
    background:#53504E;
   }
#part2 ul li img
  {
   width:25px;
   height:25px;
  }
#part2 ul li:hover ul
   {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height: auto;
    background:#2F2D2C;
    top:60px;
    margin-left:-135px;
    left:auto;
    border-radius:5px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1000;
   }
#part2 ul li ul
   {
    display:none;
   }
#part2 ul li ul li
   {
    width:190px;
    padding:10px 5px 0px 5px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1000;
   }
#part2 ul li ul li:hover
     {
      background:#2F2D2C;
     }
#part2 ul li:last-child ul li:hover
{
background:#53504E;
}
#part2 li ul li:first-child:before
      { /* the pointer tip */
       content:'';
       position:absolute;
       width:1px;
       height:1px;
       border:10px solid transparent;
       border-bottom-color:#fff;
       right:20%;
       top:-20px;
       margin-left:-5px;
      }
a
{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#fff;
}
a:hover
{
 color:#FF6600;
}
#part2 ul li ul li input
      {
       height:25px;
       width:150px;
       border-radius:5px;
       border:0;
       padding:0 0 0 5px;
      }
```

```html
<div id="part2">
    <ul>
     <li class="search-btn" onclick="myFunction()"> <img src="icon/003-search.png" name="Search" alt="Search"/></li>
     <li class="shopcard-btn"> <img src="icon/shopcard.png" name="Shopcard" alt="Shopcard"/><span class="num">3</span>
      <ul>
       <li><span class="item">Item's Name</span><span>200tk</span></li>
       <li><span class="item">Item's Name</span><span>200tk</span></li>
       <li><span class="item">Item's Name</span><span>200tk</span></li>
       <li><span class="item">Total Price</span><span>200tk</span></li>
       <li><button type="submit" name="View" class="button">View details</button></li>
        <li><button type="submit" name="View" class="button">Check Out</button></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="favorite-btn"> <img src="icon/favorite.png" name="Favorite" alt="Favorite"/><span class="num">3</span>
      <ul>
       <li><button type="submit" name="View" class="button">View details</button></li>
       <li><p><a href="registation.php">Sign</a> In to manage and view all items.</p></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="user-btn"> <img src="icon/user.png" name="Login & Registation" alt="Login & Registation"/>
      <ul>
       <li><input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="User Name" /></li>
       <li><input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password"/></li>
       <li><button type="submit" value="Login" class="button">Login</button></li>
       <li><button type="submit" name="View" class="button">Join</button></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="tracking-btn"> <img src="icon/tracking.png" name="Delivery Tracking" alt="Delivery Tracking"/>
     <ul>
       <li><input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="User Name" /></li>
       <li><input type="text" name="Password" placeholder="Order Number"/></li>
       <li><button type="submit" value="Login" class="button">Search</button></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="menu-btn"> <img src="icon/menu_icon.png" name="Menu_icon" alt="menu_icon"/>
      <ul>
       <li>Sell with us</li>
       <li>Help Center</li>
       <li>About us</li>
       <li>Downlode Apps</li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: kindly can you check attached code

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/14n9mpvBoM05HrVjeKG8uiPddJoUM-yqs/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: Nobody is going to download and run your source from Google Drive. Try publishing public TEST environment or adding full HTML/CSS/JS source here as snippets. Help us help you!

Answer (score 0):

A few things are pretty bad here in terms of CSS code style. The specificity you are using ( ids as selectors, element selectors, etc ) are probably causing you undue pain. In addition, what you are calling "anchor text showing on hover" is actually just the text below the unordered list element showing through the hovered DOM that you place in the navigation.

By adding a single `z-index: 10000` to `#primary_nav_wrap ul ul`, I was able to bring this element to the top of the render stack, solving your problem.

I would recommend re-writing some of this CSS as well, as you are building quite a brittle structure which will continue to have issues as complexity increases.

```css
#primary_nav_wrap
{
 
 height:40px;
 margin-top:11px;
 background:#fff;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:14px;
 line-height:40px;
 padding:0 70px 0 20px;
 letter-spacing:.2em;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 position:relative;
 z-index:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap .arrow:after
{
 content:'\203A';
 font-size:24px;
 color:#000;
 float:right;
 margin-right:5px;
 margin-top:-32px;
 transform:rotate(90deg);
 -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
 -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover .arrow:after
 {
  content:'\2039';
 }

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item img
{
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 padding:5px 5px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0;
  z-index: 10000;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a:before
{
 content:'\203A';
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-right:10px;
 color:black;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:250px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">

 <div class="mainbody">
  
  <ul>
        <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="index.php"><img src="./icon/home.png"/></a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Men's</a><span class="arrow"></span>
           <ul>
          <li><a href="">Traditional Wear</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Top Wear</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bottom Wear</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bags</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Accessories</a></li>
        </ul>
          <li>
     <li><a href="#">Women's</a><span class="arrow"></span>
           <ul>
          <li><a href="">Traditional Wear</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Westen Wear</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lingerie</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bages</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Jewellery</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Accessories</a></li>
           </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Kids</a><span class="arrow"></span>
           <ul>
          <li class="dir"><a href="#">Boy's</a>
     <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
          <li class="dir"><a href="#">Girl's</a>
     <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dir"><a href="#">Baby</a>
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
           </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Home & Living</a><span class="arrow"></span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Kitchen Decor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Bathroom Decor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Bedroom Decor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Dining Decor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Drawing Decor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Furniture</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Lighting</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Textile and Rugs</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Office Stationery</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
     <li><a href="#">Garden</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Offer Zone</a></li>
     </ul> 
 </div>
</nav>
```